# Having a problem with getting the right value with private variable

Tags: c++

This is a program that takes an array and print the sum of the odd (named m_sumOdd) and even (named m_sumEven) numbers of that array using class. However when i run it and enter some values like (4, 6, 9, 3, 1) the m_sumEven returns 10 and m_sumOdd returns 2037769787. What's the problem with m_sumOdd ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass {
private:
int m_sumEven;
int m_sumOdd;
public:
    myClass() {
        m_sumEven = 0;
        m_sumOdd = 0;
    }
    myClass(int arr[]) {
        for (int  i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                m_sumEven += arr[i];
            }
            else if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                m_sumOdd += arr[i];
            }
        }
        print();
    }
    void print() {
         std::cout << m_sumEven << "\t" << m_sumOdd << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    int main_arr[5];

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
         std::cin >> main_arr[j];
    }

    myClass obj(main_arr);


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I have to use this format. Means that i can only initialize the m_sumOdd and m_sumEven in the default constructor and use the second constructor to calculate the sumOdd and sumEven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not initialize your variable in C++, the default value of that variable is whatever garbage value happens to already be in that memory location. So if you initialize your privates variables as zeros (as in your non-parameterized constructor), your problem will be solved.

Comment: Yeah but i already initialize them in the default constructor.

Comment: But when you create your object like `myClass obj(main_arr);` you have overridden your default constructor, and you use this `myClass(int arr[])` constructor, and for this constructor your variables are not initialized, so, garbage value problem.

Comment: ohh now i understand. but is there is a way around it because the problem is from my uni textbook and it specify that the private variables shall be initialized in the default constructor and the other constructor find the sum

Comment: If you have to initialize your variables specifically in default constructor even though you override it, you can add `*this = myClass();` as first line in your constructor `myClass(int arr[])`, this will invoke default constructor first

Comment: Welcome, I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> the problem is from my uni textbook and it specify that the private variables shall be initialized in the default constructor and the other constructor find the sum

I'm not sure what solution the textbook is looking for, but there is a mechanism that allows one constructor to use another.

```
class myClass {
private:
    int m_sumEven;
    int m_sumOdd;
public:
    myClass() {
        m_sumEven = 0;
        m_sumOdd = 0;
    }
    myClass(int arr[]): myClass() { // <-------
        ....
```

This is called *[delegating constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor)*. This makes your `myClass(int arr[])` constructor use the `myClass()` constructor before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

The second constructor doesn't initialize the private variables like the first one.

```
    m_sumEven = 0;
    m_sumOdd = 0;
```

Put these to the second constructor as well.

Even better, put them at the declaration:

```
int m_sumEven = 0;
int m_sumOdd = 0;
```

And now you don't need the first constructor.

Unrelated: consider using `std::initializer_list` instead. This provides you a safe way to know how many items are passed to the constructor, while now you have a fixed 5 in mind which may change later.

Comment: @micheal-chourdakis I have to use the default constructor to initialize them and use another constructor to calculate the odd and even.